# gdb strange behaviour ( [next] jumps few lines back on a block code)

Tags: c++, gdb

I have notice pretty bizare bahaviour of gdb when debugging a straight block of code.
I ran gdb normally with following commands.

```
gdb ./exe
break main
run
next
```

then `[enter]` a few times.
What I got a as result was

```
35      world.generations(generations);
(gdb) 
36      world.popSize(100);
(gdb) 
37      world.eliteSize(5);
(gdb) 
41      world.setEvaluationFnc( eval );
(gdb) 
37      world.eliteSize(5);
(gdb) 
39      world.pXOver(0.9);
(gdb) 
38      world.pMut(0.9);
(gdb) 
41      world.setEvaluationFnc( eval );
(gdb)
```

There is absolutely no reason to run over those lines twice. I do not understand this behaviour. The code looks as follows:

```
(gdb) list 39
34      SimpleGA<MySpecimen> world;
35      world.generations(generations);
36      world.popSize(100);
37      world.eliteSize(5);
38      world.pMut(0.9);
39      world.pXOver(0.9);
40  
41      world.setEvaluationFnc( eval );
42  
43      world.setErrorSink(stderrSink);
```

I am not sure if i should disregard it or there something wicked going on in my code. The app uses OpenMP and is compiled to use it. However, the `info thread` says there is only one thread running. Also, everything seems to give proper results, but even executed twice there should be no problems as those are mostly some plain setters.

Did anyone seen something like this or have any hints where to investigate ? I failed on my own =).

Thanks for hints,
luk32.

Comment: Are you compiling with any optimizations turned on? Are you sure you haven't modified the source after the last compilation (gdb fetches the actual source)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the compiler rearranging the code. I suppose the "new" order still works correctly?

If possible, try to debug with optimizations turned off; that increases the likelyhood of the executable staying closer to the source code.

Comment: Ok. This is right. @Joachim Was 1st but he only commented, so I accept this one. Dunno if I can reward him. Why did not I think of it. gnu's O3 Was the cause. O0 solved the issue. It looked really bizare lol. Thank you both for fast suggestion !